# Django ORM for desktop application

Tags: python, django, orm

Recently, I have become increasingly familiar with Django. I have a new project that I am working on that will be using Python for a desktop application. Is it possible to use the Django ORM in a desktop application? Or should I just go with something like [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317899/django-projects-as-desktop-applications-how-to, if you want to use the admin web-app functionality in a desktop application.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Django people are sensible people with a philosophy of decoupling things. So yes, in theory you should be perfectly able to use Django's ORM in a standalone application.

Here's one guide I found: [Django ORM as a standalone component](http://jystewart.net/process/2008/02/using-the-django-orm-as-a-standalone-component/).

Comment: That link isn't desktop-specific, so there may be a few more gotchas. (I tried to get it running this week and ran into a few snags.) Just a heads up for everyone.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using SQLAlchemy and a declarative layer on top of it such as [Elixir](http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/wiki) if you prefer a Django-like syntax.

Comment: Also SQLAlchemy exposes a little more of the SQL design, making it a tiny bit easier to use 3rd party reporting tools.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is. The Commonsense Computing Project at the MIT media lab does that for ConceptNet,
a semantic network. You can get the source here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ConceptNet/4.0b3

Answer (score 1):

The peewee ORM has a declarative syntax that should be familiar to django users, and can be used as a standalone.  Here are the project [docs](http://charlesleifer.com/docs/peewee/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another ORM for a desktop application maybe SQLAlchemy or SQLObject.
It i possible to use the django ORM but I think other ORM are a better ones if you are going to use them standalone.

Answer (score 0):

[Camelot](http://www.python-camelot.com/) seems promising if you want to do Python desktop apps using a DB. It uses SQLAlchemy though. Haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible and is documented [in the docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage):

You need to setup django like below:

```
import django
from django.conf import settings
from myapp import myapp_defaults

settings.configure(default_settings=myapp_defaults, DEBUG=True)
django.setup()

# Now this script or any imported module can use any part of Django it needs.
from myapp import models
```