# Django Projects as Desktop applications : how to?

Tags: django, desktop

How to make Django projects packaged as desktop applications?
I found some tutorials, but is there any solution as [DjangoKit](http://jerakeen.org/code/djangokit/) , for Linux and Windows?

List of related tutorials :

- [Deploying a Django app on the desktop](http://www.silverstripesoftware.com/blog/archives/51)
- [Django application as a stand-alone desktop application](https://prudentdevs.club/make-your-django-application-as-a-stand-alone-desk/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This project started when I needed to
>   distribute a self contained user
>   installable Windows demo of a Django
>   application

[dbuilder.py](https://github.com/scaphilo/dbuilder/blob/master/dbuilder.py)

Edit: Another alternative is [Super Zippy](https://github.com/brownhead/superzippy#super-zippy), it takes a Python package and its pure Python dependencies and transforms them all into a single executable file.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to look into Appcelerator's ([link](http://www.appcelerator.com/)) [Titanium Desktop](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-desktop/) for developing web apps on the desktop.

It's fully cross platform, Linux, Mac OSX, Windows.

It's supports running **Python**, Ruby, and JavaScript code in your application all concurrently interacting with one anther in one application. It's pretty sweet.

Comment: Django is not supported yet :)

Comment: it supports python, I am pretty sure with a little out of the box thinking it could be made to use django in some manner, django is just python code so how could it not use it, unless I am missing something? They don't support frameworks, just languages and python is supported

Answer (score 5):

(Full disclosure, I'm the founder of ToDesktop. I think this is a helpful answer though)

If your Django app is already deployed as a web app then you can wrap the web app in [Electron](https://electronjs.org/).

If the web app does not need to be distributed to users (i.e.. you don't need an installer or code signing) then [Nativefier](https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier) is great for that. It's free and open-source. I made a [Nativefier guide here](https://www.todesktop.com/guides/nativefier).

If you're distributing to users then you'll probably want an installer and code signing and auto-updates for Electron. [ToDesktop](https://www.todesktop.com/) will do all that for you without any coding or configuration.
There's a [comparison of the two here](https://www.todesktop.com/nativefier-alternative).