# Can Django be used with py2exe?

Tags: python, django, py2exe

We'd like to create a Django Intranet application for mass market. We only need to support Windows users, and it needs to be very easy for a Windows admin (or "technical user") to deploy (baring in mind that most Windows admins/users have little experience with Python, etc).

Is Django + py2exe the answer? Do we need something extra, or something else?

Comment: don't you need a WEB Server to run the Django app?

Comment: Yeah, but we were wondering how we might package this to make it easier for the end user :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you require:

- Python 2.5.2
- Django (svn version at
  least 2008-06-05)
- CherryPy (web
  server)
- Py2Exe

[Tutorial](http://misunderstandings.wordpress.com/2008/06/26/django-desktop-app/)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317899/django-projects-as-desktop-applications-how-to

Comment: I think this is slightly different to the related question, since it involves needing a web server. But thanks for the link.

Comment: Ok, Nick then checkout this: http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-desktop/

Comment: I was looking at something similar using PyInstaller but it only supports up to Python 3.6 - does Py2Exe have a similar limitation/issue?

Answer (score 4):

PyInstaller has [builtin support](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Executable-From-Django) for Django applications. It will do most of the magic by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did this with Django 1.5 and python 2.7.  I didn't embed a webserver, because I really just wanted the ORM.

Here are the options I used in setup.py:

```
options = {
 "py2exe":{
           "includes": ["Cookie","htmlentitydefs"],
           "packages":["django","sqlite3","email"],
           }
 }
```