# how to run Django locally as a windows executable app

Tags: django, docker, django-deployment

I'm considering building app with Django for only one user that would run application locally on windows. I read about containerizing Django apps, but it's new for me.
My goal is to run Django server on one click like a standard windows app and connect to it on `localhost` and interact with web browser. It is even possible?

Comment: You can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657063/can-django-be-used-with-py2exe
But in general - it would be quite an effort and stability won't be great

But if *exe is not required (i.e. you have installed Python on machine) - then you can just provide *.bat file with a script - python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, but this may not be the best solution. If you want to release a Django app that can be installed on your client computer, you usually need to ensure all the dependencies are shipped with the app.

Containerising your application means it will depends on Docker runtime (or any container system you use). You will have to setup Docker with your app, or ensure your client has Docker on his machine to run it. If the destination machine runs Windows or macOS, you will need to setup docker-desktop which may be more complicated than standard Docker runtime (linux only).

But if you decide to ship your app without containerising it, it will only depends on a Python interpreter and some dependencies (Django, dateutil, etc.). In such case, using python tools like virtualenv, you may prepare a ready-to-run application by creating the venv and installing dependencies at "build time". Then, with a proper setup (MSI for Windows or DMG for macOS), you may be able to distribute the final application so the client can install and run it without any additional step (you do all the hard job yourself).

Comment: Is ```Auto PY to EXE``` will be enough for this?

Comment: As suggested by @Egor Wexler, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1657063/1887976 for that

Comment: My manager doesnt encourage Docker. Anyway I am going to use nssm.exe. All good

Answer (score -2):

Django app can be convert into .exe but it wont work as local server while click .exe because runserver command and some of django service wont support on this way as per my experiment.