# How to install django applications on a Memory Stick

Tags: python, django, windows, executable

I am currently developing an open source software based on python/django. The software should later be easy installable by a standard windows/linux users without any programming experiance. It should also be portable to different computers. The only installation that should be required on these computers should be python itself.

Is there a way to get this to work?

I already found this "dbuilder" [Django Projects as Desktop applications : how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317899/django-projects-as-)
desktop-applications-how-to

It seems to be a bit outdated and not a very smooth solution.

Are there better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a portable version of python on your memory stick. Make a batch file that runs
projname.bat file:

```
python.exe /django-app-path/manage.py runserver
```

now open a browser and browse for it
the default address will be:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

If you need to browse your app on other device that you're app is running:

get your server ip with

```
windows shell>ipconfig
linux shell@ ifconfig
```

then run your development server on that address (in the batch file):

```
python.exe /django-app-path/manage.py runserver your-ip-address:port-if-not-80
```