# create desktop app (in windows 7 by .EXE format) by django (and python 3.4)

Tags: python, django, python-3.4, desktop-application

I am tring to create windows app by Django and find this:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317899/django-projects-as-desktop-applications-how-to)

But it's not usefull for me.
is there any way to create desktop (windows .exe formatted) app by Django?

Comment: What are your requirements and why are the linked information not useful for you?

Answer (score 0):

Django it's a Python web framework and is designed for web development.

I suggest you to use C#, C++ language for Windows app development, you can use Python if you want, but it's a little bit harder.

Maybe this can help you:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/getstarted

Answer (score 0):

You can create an exe from any Python file using the PyInstaller framework:
http://www.pyinstaller.org/